# "not in this scope" error in cpp function calling

Tags: c++, function, parameters, scope

I was trying to implement mergesort in cpp. However, the Dev-cpp 5.6.1 reports some "not in this scope" error. It said, "lo", "mid", and "hi" was not declared in this scope. Can you tell me why this happens? Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void merge(int nums[], int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    int n1 = mid - lo + 1;
    int n2 = hi - mid + 1;
    /*Other implementation code omitted*/
}
int main() {
    /*code to Input numbers into nums[]*/
    merge(nums, 0, 4, 9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is nums a global variable when you are passing it as a parameter? `int[] &nums` isn't legal syntax, did you mean `int nums[]`?

Comment: I set nums[] global because there will be another function merge_sort() which also works on nums[]. Yes I mean `int nums[]`. But `int nums[]` is not using reference. Can `merge(int nums[], int lo, int mid, int hi)` modify the global nums[]?

Comment: C-style arrays in C++ are weird and don't follow normal syntax. `int nums[]` won't copy the array and changes to it will affect the passed array. Don't use global variables. What if you want `merge_sort` to work on an array that isn't nums? That is why it has parameters.

Comment: Oh I know that. I will change the code. Thanks. But another question still exists. Why is "lo", "mid", and "hi" said to be "not declared in the scope"?

Comment: Have you provided the complete code? http://ideone.com/05Q2lH

Comment: No but I will complete the code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading error messages that involve syntax errors, it is important to pay the most attention to the very first one. This is because the C++ compiler is not obligated to stop at the first error, and more errors may be produced as a consequence of the first.

In your original code, you have a syntax error in your declaration of the `nums` parameter to your `merge()` function:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int nums[10];
void merge(int[] &nums, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    int n1 = mid - lo + 1;
    int n2 = hi - mid + 1;
    /*Other implementation code omitted*/
}
int main() {
    /*code to Input numbers into nums[]*/
    merge(nums, 0, 4, 9);
}
```

You have since edited your program to remove that syntax error, but with this original code, I see the following error messages:

```
x.cc:3: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
x.cc: In function 'void merge(int*)':
x.cc:4: error: 'mid' was not declared in this scope
x.cc:4: error: 'lo' was not declared in this scope
x.cc:5: error: 'hi' was not declared in this scope
x.cc: In function 'int main()':
x.cc:3: error: too many arguments to function 'void merge(int*)'
x.cc:11: error: at this point in file
```

You reported the `was not declared in this scope` errors, but failed to mention the first one, which is pointing out the syntax error for `nums`. Because of this syntax error, the compiler failed to parse the rest of the function parameters, so it reported those identifiers as having no visible declaration.

Fixing this error removes the others. This is because the parser for the function prototype now picks up the rest of the function arguments, so those are now in scope for the rest of the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me about this! I will focus on the first error next time.